# References request for an algebraic treatment of geometry?

Tags: algebraic-geometry, reference-request, isometry

There is this book in German that seems to be perfectly what I am looking for. 
It's: Geometrie by Horst Knörrer.

Only problem is, I don't speak German. Anyone know if there is a translation into English of this book or know of any book that treats isometry groups?

Comment: Perhaps if you gave more details of what type of information you're looking for (more than stating isometry groups), we could give you a reference.

Comment: A very good book: "Glimpses of Algebra and Geometry" by Gabor Toth, 2nd edition, Springer, 2002.